# Image upload plugin for WYMeditor

Tags: jquery, wymeditor

Maybe a simple question, but is there something like a plugin for WYMeditor which makes it possible to upload files inside the editor? Or should I just use a jQuery plugin and combine those two?

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure specifically, but RefineryCMS has extended wymeditor heavily. I would take a look at their source code as a starting point. They do support image uploading.